# Reuse normalizer in ND4J/DL4J

Tags: java, deeplearning4j, nd4j

I wonder what's the proper way to reuse a normalizer in ND4J/DL4J. Currently, I save it follows:

```
final DataNormalization normalizer = new NormalizerStandardize();
normalizer.fit( trainingData );
normalizer.transform( trainingData );
normalizer.transform( testData );

try {
    final NormalizerSerializer normalizerSerializer = new NormalizerSerializer();
    normalizerSerializer.addStrategy( new StandardizeSerializerStrategy() );
    normalizerSerializer.write( normalizer, path );
} catch ( final IOException e ) {
    // ...
}
```

And load it via:

```
try {
    final NormalizerSerializer normalizerSerializer = new NormalizerSerializer();
    normalizerSerializer.addStrategy( new StandardizeSerializerStrategy() );
    final DataNormalization normalizer = normalizerSerializer.restore( path );
} catch ( final Exception e ) { // Throws Exception instead of IOException.
    // ...
}
```

Is that OK? Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find more information in the docs.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I do...

```
DataNormalization normalizer = new NormaizerStandardize();
normalizer.fit(trainingData);
normalizer.transform(trainingData);
```

save it

```
NormalizerSerializer saver = NormalizerSerializer.getDefaults();
File normalsFile = new File("fileName");
saver.write(normalizer,normalsFile);
```

restore it

```
NormalizerSerializer loader = NormalizerSerializer.getDefaults();
DataNormalization restoredNormalizer = loader.restore(normalsFile);
restoredNormalizer.transform(testData);
```

The ND4J Java Docs say that `.getDefaults()` gets a serializer, configured with strategies for the built-in normalizer implementations. As you are using `NormalizerStandardize` the `getDefaults()` offers a short-hand way of achieving the same end without explicitly adding the strategy.

Comment: Different than I do, but looks good. Do you know if there's anything documented regarding this?